# How to recover a lost zip file password (Extract Zip Spec '2.0')

Tags: passwords, linux, brute-force, zip, recovery

I want to recover my backup file, but I can't find the password. The password contains 12-20 characters (As!@$123)

```
user@PC:/media/user/MyData$ zipdetails -v backup2.zip 

0000000 0000004 50 4B 03 04 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
0000004 0000001 14          Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0000005 0000001 03          Extract OS            03 'Unix'
0000006 0000002 00 00       General Purpose Flag  0000
0000008 0000002 00 00       Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
000000A 0000004 44 81 99 48 Last Mod Time         48998144 'Mon Apr 25 16:10:08 2016'
000000E 0000004 00 00 00 00 CRC                   00000000
0000012 0000004 00 00 00 00 Compressed Length     00000000
0000016 0000004 00 00 00 00 Uncompressed Length   00000000
000001A 0000002 06 00       Filename Length       0006
000001C 0000002 0B 00       Extra Length          000B
000001E 0000006 6F 74 68 65 Filename              'other/'
                72 2F
0000024 0000002 00 00       Extra ID #0001        0000 ''
0000026 0000002 00 00         Length              0000
0000028 0000000               Extra Payload
0000028 0000002 00 00       Extra ID #0002        0000 ''
000002A 0000002 00 00         Length              0000
000002C 0000000               Extra Payload


Unexpecded END at offset 0000002C, value 50000000
Done
```

Elcomsoft is now working, I need to bruteforce the zip password but only under Linux.

Comment: What does that *(As!@$123)* blob in your text mean? Please [edit].

Comment: If you can't remember the exact combo that you usually use, just write a script and inject all your known password to do the "custom brute-force".

Answer (score 1):

There is a util named fcrackzip, you can find some info here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fcrackzip.1.html

But there's one tip i must tell you: if you need to bruteforce a 12-20 characters long password, that can contain letters, numbers and symbols: i would suggest you to forget it and leave the project. That kind of brute-force may require years with modern computation.

Comment: "many years" :D (66 sextillion years with AlphaNum(upper/lowercase) +14 Symbols and 2 million keys/sec)

Comment: well... i didnt calculate exactly the total amount of years. haha

Answer (score 1):

If the Symbols `As!@$123` are the parts you password was orignally made of I'd recommend creating a customzied bruteforce using these Symbols in order to get the password.

For this you *could* use John The Ripper or Rarcrack.

Otherwise; as KanekiDev said: good luck brute-forcing the 12-20 long password.

[image]

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. You'd have to take away the time taken for 12 characters.

Comment: @Awn and the time it takes to reboot after electric power losses...